# Calling a WebService from an ASP.net application

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis

I have a WEB application on multiple servers (Windows 2008). However on a windows 2012 server, I receive the following error

```
 Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'myservice.units.AFMService' is not defined.

Source Error:



Line 8:          Dim oService As New myservice.units.AFMService
```

The code is not precompiled, I simply copied the code from one server to another. All other pages/calls work correctly.

The Web.config has the following line

```
<add key="myservice.units.AFM" value="http://xxxxxx/xxxx/x/xxx.asmx"/
```

Any Ideas on what I could check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I was too quick to ask the question.

I re-copied the folder APP_WebRefrences and it worked